# sql запрос групп сумм с условием из другой таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть 3 таблицы(`table1`, `table2`, `table3`).

table1:

```
id1|name
----------
 1 |a     
 2 |b     
 3 |c     
 4 |d
```

table2:

```
id2|id1|id3|number 
------------------
1  |1  |1  |60    
2  |1  |1  |40   
3  |1  |1  |50    
4  |2  |3  |20    
5  |2  |3  |45     
6  |2  |3  |90
```

table3

```
id3|text  |num
--------------
1  |text1 |290    
2  |text2 |150    
3  |text3 |154    
4  |text4 |185
```

Необходимо выбрать колонки `table1.name, sum(table2.number), table3.text`, сгруппированые по `table1.name`

При этом в  результат должны попасть только такие строчки, для которых значение суммы `sum(table2.number)` строго больше значения `table3.num`.
В результат должны попасть 10 записей с максимальной суммой `sum(table2.number)`

Пример результата:

```
name | sum | text
------------------
b    | 155 | text3  --(20+45+90)>154
```

Comment: Не понятно как связывать таблицу 3 с остальными, судя по именам колонок надо брать поле id3 из второй таблицы. но для одного id1 может быть несколько разных id3 и тогда суммы брать в разрезе id3 для сравнения или еще как то ? Если же во второй таблице id3 всегда имеет только одно возможное значение для всех записей с конкретным id1 - то у вас неправильно спроектированы таблицы, нарушена 3я нормальная форма и с этим надо что то делать ...

Comment: Я кардинально переписал ваш вопрос. Проверьте, пожалуйста, что все осталось верно.

Comment: @mike в первоначально формулировке вообще сложно понять, что происходит. На мой взгляд, так значительно лучше.

Comment: @mike мне казалось, что ясно из структуры таблиц. Добавил пример и уточнение про группировку в очередь правок. В любом случае я призываю ТС'а проверить мою правку и исправить вопрос, если я что то трактовал неверно. И еще желательно указать БД, к которой такие запросы пишутся.

Comment: Да вы правы я забыл добавить что и первая таблица зависит от третьей

Comment: id1|name|id3
----------
 1 |a     |3
 2 |b     |2
 3 |c     |1
 4 |d     |3

Comment: извините хотел попроще написать,но если не совсем понятно о чем речь, то первая таблица абитуриентов вторая их результаты егэ а третья направления и нужно выяснить кто поступил.

Comment: @stkovflUser Что значит "_первая таблица зависит от третьей_" по какому полю они связаны ?

Comment: я же написал что первая зависит по id3,а вообще если затрудняетесь ответить то подскажите просто как сравнивать сумму по id из одной таблицы со значением из другой а дальше сам постараюсь

Comment: Я не затрудняюсь, я понимаю что при приведенной структуре ответ будет неверным с вероятностью процентов 70. Я не понимаю как таблица 1 связана с таблицей 3 потому что в таблице 1 нет никакого id3. Он есть в таблице 2, но для одной записи из таблицы 1 может быть _несколько_ разных id3 (судя по структуре) и вот этот момент меня и смущает, я выше уже написал, что вы должны сказать, что делать в ситуации если для записи 'b' во второй таблице окажутся строки с id3=1 и id3=4 ? Ну а сверить просто, либо сначала подклеить t2 сгруппировать, проссумировать, а потом к этому подклеить 3ю, либо наоборот

Comment: вот буквально `select t1.name, sum(t2.num), max(t3.text) from t1,t2,t3 where t2.id1=t1.id1 and t3.id3=t2.id3 group by t1.name, t1.id1 having sum(t2.num)>max(t3.num)` ну плюс подходящие сортировка и лимит, в общем то ответит на ваш вопрос, и на приведенном примере результат будет верным, но если вдруг данные будут чуть чуть другими, такими как я писал выше, то результат будет _не верным_ и ради вот тех крайних ситуаций запрос надо будет переписать начисто, совсем по другому ...

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из представленных данных запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT t1.name,t3.text,SUM(t2.number) as sum
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id1
JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id3 = t3.id3
GROUP BY t1.name, t3.text, t3.num
HAVING SUM(t2.number) > t3.num
```

Если полей и таблиц больше и такой запрос не подходит, тогда можно условие по поиску вынести подзапрос вида:

```
SELECT t3.id3,SUM(t2.number) as sum
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id3 = t3.id3
GROUP BY t3.id3,t3.num 
HAVING SUM(t2.number) > t3.num
```

А потом заджойнить всё с таблицами table1 и table2, ....